# Why can I not add two numbers in Kotlin using this source code?

Tags: kotlin

This is the code I have created to add two numbers:

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val (a, u) = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String::toInt)

    println(add(a, u))
}

fun  add(a: Int, u: Int) = a + u
```

However I keep getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Kotlin_learnKt.main(kotlin^learn.kt:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I just want to be able to prompt the user to enter two numbers, have the code add them, then return the result.

Comment: Your input string is not a number

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM Ok. So that means that my input is read as a String and in this case I cannot add Strings? If so, how do I correct this ?

Comment: readLine()!!.split(' ') gives one additional value that's empty string, which cannot be parsed into a number and throws an exception.

Comment: using `split` to read consecutive was a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

From the thrown exception stack trace it does not look like you are inputting anything so `readLine()` returns the empty string which cannot be parsed as an int value.

I recommend reading each int value separately while you troubleshoot:

```
fun readInt(message: Any?): Int {
    print(message)
    return readLine()!!.toInt()
}
val a = readInt("a = ")
val u = readInt("u = ")
println("a + u = ${a + u}")
```

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
fun readInt(message: Any?): Int {
    val promptSequence = generateSequence(
            seedFunction = {
                print(message)
                readLine()
            },
            nextFunction = { invalidInput ->
                println("Input '$invalidInput' is not an int value. Try again.")
                print(message)
                readLine()
            }
    )

    return promptSequence.map(::Scanner).first(Scanner::hasNextInt).nextInt()
}

val a = readInt("a = ")
val u = readInt("u = ")
println("a + u = ${a + u}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(vararg args: String) {  
    val input = Scanner(System.`in`)  
    val a = input.nextInt()  
    val b = input.nextInt()  
    println(a + b)
}
```